QGIS Python error AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable
How can I fix this Python error when I open QGIS project?
File "C:\Users/mohammed.hayder/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ee_plugin\ee_plugin.py", line 125, in updateLayers
import ee
File "C:\Users/mohammed.hayder/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ee_plugin_init_.py", line 36, in wrapping_ee_import
module.Initialize()
File "C:\Users\mohammed.hayder\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee_init_.py", line 115, in Initialize
data.initialize(
File "C:\Users\mohammed.hayder\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\data.py", line 210, in initialize
_install_cloud_api_resource()
File "C:\Users\mohammed.hayder\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\data.py", line 280, in _install_cloud_api_resource
_cloud_api_resource = cloud_api_utils.build_cloud_resource(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\mohammed.hayder\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee_cloud_api_utils.py", line 133, in build_cloud_resource
http_transport = httplib2.Http(timeout=timeout)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\mohammed.hayder\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\httplib2shim_init.py", line 117, in init
pool = self.make_pool(proxy_info=proxy_info)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\mohammed.hayder\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\httplib2shim_init.py", line 45, in _default_make_pool
if isinstance(proxy_info, collections.Callable):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'

You have an older version of the Google Earth Engine plugin installed that doesn't work with python 3.10+.  Either update the plugin or uninstall it.


@MohammedAL-Mamory  did this answer your question? If so, consider accepting it or providing feedback so it can be improved.
